# float:center -> float:left; div container adds space at bottom

Tags: html, css

When moving my div container from float:center; to float:left;

Ideally i'd like for the button to touch the bottom of the div "self"

It adds extra space below my contact button.
Any suggestions?
I've tried playing with margin, padding,overflow:hidden; etc inside the div container .self in the CSS file but with no luck.

```css
body{
    /*background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);*/
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}

.self {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    height:auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    float:left;
}

.title {
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul.school {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}​

.degrees{
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: black;
}

button:hover, a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Steven Amerman">
    <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="..\css\index.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <title>Steven Amerman</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="self">
        <img src="..\images\Steven.png" alt="Steven Amerman" style="width:100%">
        <h1>Steven Amerman</h1>
        <p class="title">Software Developer</p>
            <ul class="school">
                <li><img src="../images/wvuIcon.png" id="wvuIcon" alt="WVU" style="width:20px; height:20px">   West Virginia University</li> 
            </ul>   
            <p class="degrees">B.S. in Computer Science</p>
         <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/steven-amerman/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
        
        <p><button>Contact</button></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdVpt.png)
[no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyePS.png)

Comment: Just a quick note - `float: center` is not an actual declaration. You can see some possible declarations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Apologies, so when its not set to float:left, it reverts to being center oriented; Without the space

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the `p` tag's margin containing the contact button.  You should change its margin to 0, for instance:

```
.self p:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Why does the margin of the last child of .self not have an issue when float isn't used?

This has solved my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<p></p>` tags around the button at the bottom.

```css
body {
  /*background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);*/
  background-color: ghostwhite;
}

.self {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  float: left;
}

.title {
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul.school {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

​ .degrees {
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Steven Amerman">
  <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\css\index.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <title>Steven Amerman</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="self">
    <img src="..\images\Steven.png" alt="Steven Amerman" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Steven Amerman</h1>
    <p class="title">Software Developer</p>
    <ul class="school">
      <li><img src="../images/wvuIcon.png" id="wvuIcon" alt="WVU" style="width:20px; height:20px"> West Virginia University</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="degrees">B.S. in Computer Science</p>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/steven-amerman/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>

    <button>Contact</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This ended up removing the margin from the linkedin button and the contact button. This works as well with adding padding to either or i'm assuming?

Comment: @Samerman Yeppers. You could either add a margin to the top of the `button` tag or the bottom of the linkedin icon :). I'd recommend adding the margin to the top of the `button` instead of modifying the `margin-bottom` of the last `<p>` tag. As this button has no business being wrapped in a `<p>` tag, also adding the margin is less code.